# Why doesn't work properly and doesn't read the inputs?

Tags: c

I have this code, simple and problemless, it seems that everything is ok here, but when I run it it shows me numbers from 0 to 99 (it should firstly read some input). What is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
     int N;
     int schools[98];
     char string[20];
     int number;
     scanf("%d", &N);

     int i;
     for(i=0; i<=99; ++i) schools[i] = 0;
     for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
      scanf("%s", string);
      scanf("%s", string);
      scanf("%d", number);
      schools[number]++;
     }

     int min = N;
     for(i=0; i<=99; ++i) if(schools[i] < min)
           min = schools[i];

     for(i=0; i<=99; ++i){
      if(schools[i] == min) printf("%d, ", i);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're accessing `schools` out of bounds in the first loop. If you want to set all its values to zero, just say `int shools[98] = {};`

Comment: Multiple `scanf()` to read to the same array `string`?

Comment: Your third loop is a waste. Remove it.

Comment: stupid mistake, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0; i<=99; ++i) schools[i] = 0;
```

Array of out bound access. UB

```
scanf("%d", number);
```

`number` is never initialized so this is UB.
It should be

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Scan to the address of the variable.

```
 scanf("%s", string);
 scanf("%s", string);
```

This doesn't make sense so put together your code is not good as you think it is.